# Drupal 404 error not found on user/login, register

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

After a few changes on my website, I cannot access anymore login page.

Everything is working fine, like index page, articles, but /user/login page gives me 404 not found error.

Whats wrong? I checked .htaccess file, didnt see anything wrong... What should I check?

My website is rechindebahlui.ro

Comment: Stupid question, but did you clear the cache already? With Drush or Drupal console.

Comment: I can`t use Drupal console because I can`t log in. The website is rechindebahlui.ro and I can`t access login page to login to Drupal. It is hosted by globehosting server. I didn`t have any file from website in my computer. So I can`t access  example.com/admin

Comment: It sounds like .htaccess does not exist in the root. Check that the provided Drupal 8 .htaccess file exists in the application root. Maybe post what's inside of your htacces

Comment: .htaccess exists in root, I dunno how to post 7500 characters long file, the maximum limit is around 500

Comment: Oh didn't realize it was so big.. I still suspect it's cache then as long you are sure you didn't changed anything in the core & the htacces is getting picked up. Can't u ssh into the server and run drupal console from there?

Comment: That`s what I should do... i will ssh and run drupal console :)

Comment: Ok, good luck! Keep me posted :)

Comment: Wimanicesir, I can`t ssh or use drush.. it didn`t work. It can`t be from Core or htaccess because I downloaded new files, by default. Also, I cleared cache from tmp. I could give you my skype if u wanna...

Comment: Well even if all files are good, it's still possible you need to rebuild the cache. That's the biggest frustration when developing drupal sites :) Why can't u ssh? Don't you own the server rights? Or do you have any error when trying to ssh? You should really try to rebuild the cache before starting searching for other mistakes. I'm not going to skype you however, I'm at work myself..

Comment: I found this drupal page, which contains a function in code to clear caches..
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/8.2.x
If you could manage to run this, then we can start searching for something else

Comment: I own server rights, I can`t ssh due Response: 530 Login authentication failed
Error: Critical error: Could not connect to server, but password and user are 100% correct. Thanks for your interest. Your suggested function is located in core/includes/common.inc. I forgot to mention I have a doubt that these problems are after updating to D8.x from an older version.

Comment: NEWS: I could login to drupal console /admin, deleting database and install another database... So the problem is from database?

Comment: Cache rebuild fixes things in the database as well. So yeah, the problem was in the db but it still was probably from old references to not existing code.

Good that it is fixed, but I would really recommend trying to fix the ssh for future problems :)

Answer (score 1):

if you can install drush then please run `drush ws` command to find out what's in the Drupal logs, to hopefully get more information.